# Using regexp in Google Analytics Goal Funnel steps

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have a goal that can be reached from two pages on my website, for example, /page1 and /page2. I've made a regular expression for the first 'Required step' of the visualization funnel:

```
^/(page1|page2)$
```

If i apply it as a filter in the Top Content report - it works fine. But there's nothing registered in the conversion funnel. I actually couldn't find any information about funnel steps - is it even possible to use regexp there just like it's done in the Goal page URL?

Comment: For now i'm generating the same virtual pageview on both of that pages and use it as a first step, it works for me, but it looks not very good.

Answer (score 62):

I've just been bitten by this. The URLs in the funnel steps are the same as the Goal Destination URL:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1116091?hl=en#matchTypes states

> There are three diferent match types that define how Google Analytics identifies a URL for either a goal or a funnel. **The match type that you select for your goal URL also applies to the URLs in the funnel**, if you create one.

So you can only have regex matches in your funnel steps, if you've chosen Regular Express **in the Destination dropdown**.

I had the same problem as you. I'd chosen "Equal to" in the dropdown for the destination URL but was using "Begins with" style matches in my funnel steps and therefore getting 0 entries showing in my funnel visualisation.

Comment: So if the 'Destination' under the Goals Details section is set to 'Regular Expression' then you can also use a Regex in the steps?

Comment: Yup - and if you've had analytics running for a while, you should be able to test the matches using the *Verify this Goal* option at the bottom of the Goal Details section

Answer (score 6):

The following article states that the goal steps should be defined as regex as well.

> http://www.analyticsmarket.com/blog/create-google-analytics-goals
>
> > "Each step should be defined as a regular expression as well."

(almost at the very bottom of the page)

Hope it helps

Comment: Additional context: This is because for Match Type they state: "We recommend using the Regular Expression Match type every time." So as other answers have stated, it seems to pick it up from the Destination selection.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the first character: `^`.