# Google Analytics Goal Funnel Issues

Tags: google-analytics

I am attempting to create goal funnels in GA for dynamic asp.net based pages. The funnel currently looks as follows:

```
/
/market_home.aspx
/Category.aspx
/product.aspx
/Cart.aspx
/Checkout.aspx
/OrderReview.aspx
/Confirmation.aspx
```

The market_home, Category and product pages are dynamic and will contain various parameters ie:

```
/market_home.aspx?id=1
/Category.aspx?id=1
/product.aspx?id=1
```

I am using regular expression as my match setting (have tried head match as well). I still get two of my market home pages not being captured. It is only 2 out of 18.

I can't seem to figure out why it catches some, but not all of the traffic.

I also am not capturing incoming/outgoing traffic that is not at the start of the funnel. In other words, those visitors being captured in the funnel appear to complete the entire thing from start to finish. There are no visitors dropping out in the middle anywhere, which I can't believe.

The beginning of the URL will not change.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem, i even asked about it couple days ago: [Using regexp in Google Analytics Goal Funnel steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209041/using-regexp-in-google-analytics-goal-funnel-steps)

I beleive the thing is that RegExp don't work properly in funnel steps. My solution for this is generating the same virtual pageview in every dynamically generated page and use it in the funnel. Goog practice is to create a separate profile for it and filter out those virtuals in the main to avoid data distortion.